# Why I cannot open any file in a new tab in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am new in Vue.js and I try to make a website using Vue. I want to open some files in new tab but when I try to open new file it gives me this link http://localhost:8080/assets/cv.pdf and redirect to home page. Please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7XJV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5U2M.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRaNZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMwWZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylGP9.png)

Comment: Can you please provide your code in your question instead of serving images?

Comment: <a @click="openPdf()">Download CV</a>

methods: {
    openPdf(){
  window.open("./../../assets/cv.pdf") 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The public Folder

In the public folder, create **any directory** and put pdf there and refer to this path

http://localhost:8080/**any directory**/cv.pdf

> Any static assets placed in the [public](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) folder will simply be copied
> and not go through webpack. You need to reference them using absolute
> paths.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should do it, if you want to open your file in a new tab:

**1. Move your file**

You have to move `cv.pdf` to the `public` folder in your project.

**2. Call the file**

```
openPdf() {
      window.open('/cv.pdf', '_blank').focus();
    }
```

You can create folders in public as you want and should refer in `('/cv.pdf', '_blank')` to that folder. `/` would refer to `public` in this case.

Comment: @OzanBilgiç Please note, that the other solution you tried not generally opens the file in a new tab. Thats why you need to apply `_blank`. If this helped you it would be nice if you accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should open file like so:

```js
window.open('file:///...fileFullPath');
```

Comment: window.open("window.open('file:///./../../assets/cv.pdf');") 
I did it like this, but the same page shown

Comment: that is relative path, use absolute path